# Regex performance improvement

Tags: c#, .net, regex

How can I improve the performance of this regex:

```
^([A-Za-z0-9+/=])*$
```

This is used to match string having 0 or more of **A-Z, a-z, 0-9, +, /. =**

EDIT:
This is the code:

```
internal static class Base64Determinator
    {
        private static Regex base64Regex;

        static Base64Determinator()
        {
            var base64Pattern = "^(?>[A-Za-z0-9+/=]?)*$";
            base64Regex = new Regex(base64Pattern, RegexOptions.Compiled);
        }

        internal static bool IsBase64(string input)
        {
            return input != null && base64Regex.IsMatch(input);
        }
    }
```

I am testing it in a loop in nunit:

```
[Test]
        public void TestInputs()
        {
            var inputs = new List<Tuple<string, bool>>
            {
                new Tuple<string, bool>(null, false),
                new Tuple<string, bool>("asd", true),
                new Tuple<string, bool>("qwertyuiop", true),
                new Tuple<string, bool>("QWERTYUIOP", true),
                new Tuple<string, bool>(
                    "QWERTYUIOPrfweiowcq489ynOILSDKFJSLDJfLKsdjflksdjflskdjfLSKDJflkLSKJFWIOEFJOIJSFLDKJflSDJFLKSJfsl",
                    true),
                new Tuple<string, bool>("=+/Z0", true),
                new Tuple<string, bool>("=+/Z01234567890", true),
                new Tuple<string, bool>("!@#$%^&*()P", false),
                new Tuple<string, bool>("!", false),
                new Tuple<string, bool>("<", false),
                new Tuple<string, bool>(">", false),
                new Tuple<string, bool>(".", false),
                new Tuple<string, bool>("qwertyuiopoiuytrewqwertyuioplkjhgfdsadfghjklmnbvcxzxcvbnm<script>", false),
                new Tuple<string, bool>("qwertyuiopoiuytrewqwertyuioplkjhgfdsadfghjklmnbvcxzxcvbnm", true),
            };

            var startNew = Stopwatch.StartNew();
            for (int j = 0; j < 10000000; j++)
            {
                //inputs.ForEach(i => Assert.AreEqual(i.Item2, Base64Determinator.IsBase64(i.Item1)));
                inputs.ForEach(i => Base64Determinator.IsBase64(i.Item1));
            }

            startNew.Stop();

            Console.WriteLine(startNew.Elapsed);
        }
```

This takes approx 2.36 mins. I have seen other implementations that take 2 secs. So I am wondering if there is a better way to form this regex with minimum backtracking.

Thanks,
Rashmi

Comment: What's the problem with the performance at the moment?

Comment: Performance depends on a lot of things, including the input. Please provide a good [mcve] that reproduces your performance problem, and describe that problem more specifically: what is the measured performance, what is your expected performance, and what have you already tried to improve things. Note that one of the most important things you can and should to do improve performance of the .NET `Regex` class is to make sure your `Regex` object is only ever created once, reused whenever you need it, and that you use the `Compiled` option.

Comment: Using an atomic group might help, but why did you add the nested `?` quantifier?  Just use the `*`, and put it inside the group: `"^(?>[A-Za-z0-9+/=]*)$"`.  But I think the biggest problem is the way you're calling `IsMatch()`.  Try compiling the regex when you declare the variable, not in the constructor.

Comment: @AlanMoore its a static constructor, so will be called only once. What do u mean by compiling the regex, do u mean initiating it as I have done it or is there a better way to do it?

Comment: Never mind, I just wasn't familiar with static constructors.   What other implementation have you seen that takes 2 seconds?  And what does that mean, exactly?

Comment: @AlanMoore implementations in C# code not related to Regex are taking 2 seconds. Such as putting the valid characters in a lookup table and iterating through each character in the input string to validate the input. This is manual code. I assumed regex would be faster. The only thing, I can think of is that probably there is lot of backtracking happening with my regex.

Comment: If you used the atomic group, there won't be any backtracking, but there is still overhead.  A regex will never be as fast as purpose-written, low-level code.  However, that difference sounds too large.  Can you show the other code you're using?

Answer (score 0):

Performance depends upon the complexity of the input. You can make use of Regex.MatchTimeout property. 
You can define the Time span(say 200 ms) depending on your requirement and it times out appropriate message can be displayed.

Regex.Match Method (String, String, RegexOptions, TimeSpan)